# Removing business information from all sorts of business directories

Tags: google

The business website is listed on a lot of directories, most of which we did not authorize. We attempted to contact and remove all the listings and were somewhat successful, but some websites don't have any contact information or have been unresponsive.

The problem is that an incorrect number is listed and our client is receiving a lot of calls on his cell phone.

Is there a service that goes through and removes all listings somehow? I did some Google searching, but I couldn't find anything. Not sure if it's because no service like that exists or if I'm not typing in the right keywords.

Comment: Sorry but requesting tools, resources and services is considered off-topic on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: A lot of them allow you to claim a listing, register, and change the particulars and add information. Most that do not do this, scrape their information from websites including the ones I just mentioned that allow you to change the information. Claiming the listing on many or all of the major sites should in time straighten out much of the rest.

Comment: You could google for the wrong number, find the sites where it's listed and "shotgun" email the WHOIS administrators for those domains. It's not 100%, but it should help.